# Interacting particle systems with spatially inhomogeneous hydrodynamic equations

Tags: pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics, stochastic-processes

Are there known examples of spatially inhimogeneous PDE appearing as hydrodynamic equations of interacting particle systems?  In particular, I wonder whether a spatially inhomogeneous reaction diffusion equation such as 
$$u_t - \Delta u = f(x, u)$$
with $f$ non-constant in $x$ appears in the literature.  Intuitively, it seems like this could be done by making the generator of the particle system depend on space (in a non-translationally invariant way), but everything I have seen in the literature treats the translationally invariant case (and presumably this is the reason the coefficients of the resulting equations depend only on the solution $u$, not on the space variable $x$).

Answer (score 2):

A very well studied nonlinear equation of this type is the [Gross–Pitaevskii equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross%E2%80%93Pitaevskii_equation),

$$i\hbar\frac{\partial\Psi(\mathbf{r},t)}{\partial t} = \left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 + V(\mathbf{r}) + g(\mathbf{r})\vert\Psi(\mathbf{r},t)\vert^2\right)\Psi(\mathbf{r},t)$$

It's a quantum problem, so there is an imaginary unit $i$ in front of the time derivative. For a numerical solution one usually makes a Wick rotation $t\mapsto i\tau$ to remove the $i$ and work with a diffusion equation (here is an [example](https://journals.aps.org/pre/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevE.62.7438) of such a procedure). Spatial inhomogeneities play a crucial role in applications to a [cold-atom trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_trap_(atoms)).

Comment: I don't see how this addresses my question.  The example you provided uses a finite-difference method, but I'm interested in interacting particle systems and their scaling limits, not numerics (see the review article by Claudio Landim).

Comment: well, the Gross–Pitaevskii equation does describe a strongly interacting system, a collection of atoms that condense into a collective state (Bose-Einstein condensate) at low temperatures; it can hardly get more "interacting" than that....